# Reserve memory in RAM and in the desired physical position

Tags: linux, kernel, memory, c, ram

I'm trying reserved 2GB in RAM, but i like reserved in the start memory, in the 0x00000000 position to 0x80000000, Can I do it?

I read in the LDD3 that you can reserver spaces in the memory, but in virtual, and I need to reserved this memory in the first position in the RAM.

Can I do it and How?

Comment: Check [this](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/reserved-memory/reserved-memory.txt) out ...